# Deactivate text selection and use select element with firefox 40

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, onmousedown

In my application, we use this pattern a lot:

```html
<select name="select" onfocus=this.select; onClick=this.focus();>
  <option value="value1" selected>Value 1</option> 
  <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
</select>

<script>
document.onmousedown = new Function("return false");
</script>
```

The line `document.onmousedown = new Function("return false");` is aimed to prevent text selection in the page. Unfortunalty, it also blocks the propagation of the mousedown event to the select element. The workarround we use is the callbacks `onfocus=this.select; onClick=this.focus();`.

My problem is that it doesn't work with Firefox 40 : clicking on the select box does nothing. (works fine with 39)

I can remove the line `document.onmousedown = new Function("return false");` to repair the select box but it would allow text selection in the page.

My question is : what are my options to have both the working select box and the not working text selection with Firefox 40 ?

Comment: Can't you just use CSS? `-moz-user-select: none; user-select: none;` (and any required vendor prefixes)

Comment: @RGraham Thx, I was to focused on what to do with the select element to search other ways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS.

```
.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Then apply the `noselect` class (or whatever you want to call it) to any elements whose text you don't want to be selectable.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting) that discusses support of those different css properties in different browsers.